# Turn off vertical indent guide intellij 2018.2

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-idea-2018

I want to turn off Vertical Indent Guide but I don't find this option in Intellij 2018.2 . Has this feature been moved or renamed?

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out myself. It's at `Preferences/Settings -> Editor -> General -> Appearance -> Show Indent Guides`

Comment: I find that option doesn't do anything